# PHP find link in string

Tags: php

I have a string in php example below.

```
$string = "This is my website example.org check it out!";
if( preg_match( '/\w+\.(?:com|org)/i', $string, $matches)) {
var_dump( $matches[0]);
echo '' . $matches[0] . '';
}
```

It will echo out

```
string(11) "example.org" example.org
```

I need it to only echo out only

example.org

Comment: take out the line with the var_dump

Comment: You should not rewrite the whole question to ask something else. Just add "update" text. As of your question, please, see manual about `var_dump`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a regular expression to do this. Here is a start:

```
$string = "This is my website example.org check it out!";
if( preg_match( '/\w+\.(?:com|org)/i', $string, $matches)) {
    // var_dump( $matches[0]);
    // echo '<a href="' . $matches[0] . '">' . $matches[0] . '</a>';
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

The regex is:

```
\w+\.(?:com|org)
^   ^^
|   |Match either com or org
|   Match a period
Match one or more word character [A-Za-z0-9_]
```

This [will output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q4vbDz):

```
string(11) "example.org"
```

You will need to adapt it to include subdomains and protocols, if necessary.

Comment: It works great except how would I get it to just echo the domain out only, not string(11) "". sub domains would be good to how would you do that? Thank you!